# Process.Start() under asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, iis-7.5, w3wp.exe

According to [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0w4h05yb.aspx) :

> ASP.NET Web page and server control code executes in the context of
>   the ASP.NET worker process on the Web server. If you use the Start
>   method in an ASP.NET Web page or server control, the new process
>   executes on the Web server with **restricted permissions**. The
>   process does not start in the same context as the client browser, and
>   does not have access to the user desktop.

**Which** *account* precisely is the *"restricted permissions"* ?

Example :

- I'm logged to win7 as `RoyiN`
- windows authentication is *enabled*
- Impersonation is *enabled* as `BobK` **at** web.config ( all over the site)
- The `W3WP` user is `UserA` (not network nor ApplicationPoolIdentity).

In  C# I do `Process.start("....cmd.exe...")` ( **with** `Startinfo` credentials as : "`Martin`","`Password`","`Domain`")

- Who is the efficient `account` which finally runs `cmd.exe` ?
- To whom "restricted permissions" is actually regarding ?

Comment: Hope that chat helped somewhat - to answer your 2 questions:  "Who is the account which actually runs cmd.exe ?" => UserA. "To whom "restricted permissions" is actually regarding ?" => restricted permissions refers to the (usual) case of w3wp user being app pool identity, which has reduced rights. In your case, "UserA"

Comment: @JerKimball please notice that Startinfo _does_ provide credentials.

Comment: Ok, in that case, the new process should launch under the same identity as whatever user/domain you specify in the process start info.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Impersonation won't come into play here, since under the hood, `Process.Start` is relying on one of two native Win32 calls:

If ProcessStartInfo.UserName is provided:

```
CreateProcessWithLogonW(startInfo.UserName, startInfo.Domain, ...)
```

[CreateProcessWithLogonW](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682431%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

And if not:

```
CreateProcess(null, cmdLine, null, null, true, ...)
```

[CreateProcess](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682425%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

The `null`s passed into CreateProcess are what's probably biting you; from MSDN:

> The lpSecurityDescriptor member of the structure specifies a security descriptor for the main thread. If lpThreadAttributes is NULL
>   or lpSecurityDescriptor is NULL, the thread gets a default security
>   descriptor. The ACLs in the default security descriptor for a thread
>   come from the process token.

Note it says from process token, not calling thread - the impersonated identity doesn't get a chance to join the party since it's bound to the thread.

Comment: Im not using impersonation in my code , it is written in the web.cofig. so the whole site is under impersonation !

Comment: @RoyiNamir, it does not really matter who wrote the code for impersonation - behavior will be exactly the same if using either one that is  already part of ASP.Net or some manual one because eventually it will come down to the same native call. Web.config can't change account the worker process runs under - it just triggers impersonation on the threads that run the request.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov so the w3wp user permissions wont have any usages....right  ?  cause all the threads will be executed by impersonated user.

Comment: null is not involved here. ( as i run the process with credentials via `startinfo`. forgot to mentione and truly sorry.updated the question.)

Answer (score 2):

I believe the MSDN entry refers to the fact that even if impersonation is enabled and you're under a specific user context, the new process will be spawned by the process - and impersonation occurs at thread level. That said, i do believe it would run under the 'UserA' context.

Here's the pertinent KB entry:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/889251

Notice that the same entry describes how to use CreateProcessAsUser to allow for impersonation.

Comment: This. By default, the spawned process would be launched as whatever Identity is running the App Pool. The only way to get a process launched as another user context would be to p/invoke it out.

Comment: But as @OnoSendai said, Impersonation happens at the Thread level, Process.Start forks out using P/invoke internally to the win32 call CreateProcessWithLogonW or CreateProcess (depending on if you have UserName set in ProcessStartInfo)...actually, lemme put this in an answer.

Answer (score 2):

As I found out when trying to solve [this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13482145/git-ssh-hanging-when-called-from-mvc-webapi), lots of little things are different. It may run under RoyiN, but you may find that USERPROFILE is set to C:\Windows\system32\config\systemprofile, and not your /Users/RoyiN folder.

Depending on what you're trying to do, that can cause some problems. In my case, starting a git process would hang forever. Not only were USERPROFILE and HOME wrong, I also found out that impersonated users do not play well with mapped network drives.