# How to open an exe application on the server using webapplication?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

In my Web application I need to open an Autodesk inventor exe on the server. I tried some thing but it is not working while hosting  in IIS. Here is my code:

```
 Dim info = New System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo()
        info.FileName = "C:\Program Files\Autodesk\Inventor 2013\Bin\Inventor.exe"
        info.UseShellExecute = True
        Dim process = New System.Diagnostics.Process()
        process.StartInfo = info
        process.Start()
```

What is the problem. anyone have any idea?

Comment: _"I tried some thing_" - what? _"but it is not working"_ - that is not an error, show the exact message.

Comment: Please have a look [Process.Start() under asp.net?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14074069/process-start-under-asp-net)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is probably a permissions thing.

Your IIS/asp.net process doesn't have security access to that folder to execute the app.

Broadly speaking you need to give the permissions to the user so it can execute the app.

First go to the files on your server that are inside a valid website via RDC and right click on them, then go to properties and click Security tab.

You will see some user accounts and permissions. Depending the server setup (dif versions of IIS, running plesk, etc) you might have different names but look for something thats has iis in the name.

You need to then goto the autodesk exe and give the permissions for the account you found so that it can execute it.

Comment: Ah ok well its probably a permissions thing then. Your IIS/asp.net process doesn't have security access to that folder to execute the app.

Comment: have you tested the code by putting a simple app within the website folder and tried running that? Where did you get the launch app code snippet from?

Answer (score 0):

Before doing anything, that exe file should be runnable by IIS and network accounts.

Comment: you can do it by right-click on the folder, Properties > Security > Edit.

Comment: BTW usually you should grant all the folder.